# akka grpc custom authentication

Tags: scala, http, authentication, akka, grpc

I'm using akka gRpc (scala) and looking for a way to authenticate grpc calls by using a custom challenge response authentication. i.e. the client calls the grpc service with some key/identity, the service responds with a challenge, which the client signs with something that the server can verify.

I've been looking at grpc interceptors, but is that a good idea? can the interceptor in the server communicate back with the client which will also need an interceptor to respond to the challenge request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Challenge-response authentication is not very easy in interceptors. Interceptors primarily manage Metadata, and the client only sends request metadata at the very beginning of the call; there's no opportunity for the client to send the challenge response.

In Java/Scala, it is possible to make an interceptor that would do this, but it is pretty complicated. The interceptor could issue two RPCs: the first receives the challenge, and the second is the "real" RPC with the challenge response and the actual request. This requires the interceptor to buffer the sent messages and do things similar to a retry interceptor.

You can have a separate "login" RPC method that could do challenge-response via a bidirectional stream. But the result of the handshake would generally need to be a "bearer token" that could be included in future requests without any handshake. But at that point it's little better than OAuth/JWT.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Is there any example at all of interceptors in akka? ideally of a retry interceptor?